# Atomicity with asynchronous execution

Tags: async

Given code such as

```
(defun some-code ()
  (url-retrieve my-url #'my-callback)
  (setq *a-global-var* (some-func *a-global-var*))
  ...)

(defun my-callback (status &rest args)
  (setq *a-global-var* (another-func *a-global-var*)))
```

How can I ensure that the two updates of `*a-global-var*` happen atomically? In other words, how can I prevent the callback from changing `*a-global-var*` while `some-func` is running? I searched the Emacs documentation for a while, but I didn't find anything on the semantics of asynchronous operations.

Comment: What do asynchronously executed callbacks have to do with atomicity? That aside, what definition of it do you use here? I'd be seriously concerned if the mere act of setting a variable were to fail halfway...

Comment: "I didn't find anything on the semantics of asynchronous operations." - Emacs doesn't have asynchronous operations, hence no semantics.

Comment: can you  just wrap it in atomic-change-group?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Atomic-Changes.html

Comment: @JohnKitchin My understanding of atomic-change-group is that it's about changes to buffers, not updates to variable values.

Comment: @wasamasa  I have edited a sentence to make clear what kind of atomicity I need.

Comment: In `some-code`: `(put '*a-global-var* :locked t) ...some-func... (put *a-global-var* :locked nil)`; In `my-callback`: `(unless (get '*a-global-var* :locked) (setq *a-global-var* ...))`.

Comment: I was going to suggest some kind of lock mechanism also. I have used a while loop to wait until something was finished before running the next function before.

Comment: The comment of npostavs is important. `url-retrieve` uses `url-http` which uses sentinels for the callback. Sentinels only run when emacs is waiting for user input. See: [the section Sentinels of the elisp-documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html). So you do not have the problem of non-atomic writes to a variable.

Comment: @Tobias That's a very helpful comment, thanks! There is no reference to sentinels in the documentation of `url-retrieve`, and I had never heard about them before, so in a way you provided the missing documentation of asynchronous semantics in Emacs, at least for `url-retrieve`.

Comment: @Drew The comment by Tobias contains the answer to my question - there is nothing I need to do.

Comment: @Drew I put the comment into an answer. That should round up this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@npostavs made this comment on the question:

> "I didn't find anything on the semantics of asynchronous operations." - Emacs doesn't have asynchronous operations, hence no semantics.

That comment is important. `url-retrieve` uses `url-http` which uses sentinels for the callback. Sentinels only run when emacs is waiting for user input. See: [the section Sentinels](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html) of the elisp-documentation. So you do not have the problem of non-atomic writes to a variable.